# Pass parameter with url_for in HTML button

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to pass some argument to url_for from HTML when I click a button.
Main problem is that there is no data coming from any form.

Excuse me if there is some easy solution for this as this is my first time developing webpage with Python Flask.

I tried this in HTML code (welcome_user.html):

```html
<html lang="en">
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}Welcome {{user}}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}
<div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="toggle-button" onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for ( 'user_del' , usr = {{ user }} ) }}'">Delete User</button>
</div>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Python flask server side code:

```
@app.route("/welcome_<usr>")
def user_welcome(usr):
    try:
        return render_template("welcome_user.html", user=usr)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f"Error {exc} while displaying user welcome page.")

@app.route("/user_deletion")
def user_del(user):
    try:
        fn_obj.delete_user(user)
        return render_template("index.html", usr=user)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f"Error {exc} while deleting user...")
```

But this is throwing some error while rendering the html page itself. Here is the full traceback:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2021 22:27:33] "GET /welcome_new_user001 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<root_path>\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "<root_path>\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "<root_path>\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "<root_path>\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "<root_path>\flask\app.py", line 1535, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "<root_path>\flask\app.py", line 1698, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function for 'user_welcome' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
Error expected token ':', got '}' while displaying user welcome page.
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2021 22:27:34] "GET /welcome_new_user001?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2021 22:27:34] "GET /welcome_new_user001?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2021 22:27:34] "GET /welcome_new_user001?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have used brackets inside brackets `{{}}`, use this

In your route add this

```
@app.route("/user_deletion<user>")
```

Now in html use this

```
 `"window.location.href={{ url_for ( 'user_del' , user =  user ) }}"`
```

You should return something in the except part so that no error is generated.

Comment: Do you mean I should use something like: 
`onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for ( 'user_del' , user = user ) }}'"`
in this case? I have tried all these combinations and did not work for me ;(

Comment: is there same error , have you returned something in except statement. also you don't have any paramter in the route and you are passing it in the function user_del.

Comment: Yes I am now returning a page in except statement also. But it is giving me `TypeError: user_del() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'`. In HTML button, I am passing `onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for ( 'user_del' , user = user ) }}'"`. Everything else is same as the original question.

Comment: you didn't notice what the second part of comment says, haven't defined any variable in the path and passed the variable to the function, that's the error says

Comment: I'm lost. Can you please help me out here? How do I define the variable inside HTML and pass it to the url_for() function? Whlie rendering welcome_user.html, I am passing the variable as `user`. Now how do I store it in another variable in HTML and pass to the function further?

Comment: add this line to `@app.route("/user_deletion<user>")` this will work. I edited the answer look at it, also you don't need to define the variable passed through render_template you can access them like `{{user}}` , if you already have jinja tags like {% %} then you don't need `{{}}` like `{{ {{ }} }}` this will give error see the [docs] (https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233942/discussion-between-asif-iqbal-and-charchit).